# Details for using onChange trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onchange

I want to prevent people other than myself from adding, deleting or hiding certain rows and columns on a sheet. Some questions, driven at least in part by the convoluted online documentation!!! The function myFunction(e) is installed by some code I run just one time and I can see that the trigger has been installed.

1 - I see that INSERT_ and REMOVE_ ROW and COLUMN are valid changeType enums but I can't find a complete list of that enum to know if there is a HIDE_ type as well. Like, what is the OTHER for and how can I differentiate various possible events that trigger that?

2 - I'd also like to prevent changes to the View > Freeze setting but don't know if onChange gets triggered by that.

3 - I can install the onChange trigger manually or programatically and in the onChange trigger I can get the event object (e). Is there any documentation of the members of that event object? I need to grab the e.range object (if there is one) and see what the row and column numbers are.

4 - does the onChange fire BEFORE the action is completed or AFTER? And if it is after then can I "undo" the change? And if it is before then can I prevent the change from happening? How?

5 - If I determine that a "bad thing" has been done (or attempted) then I want an "authorization" step to see if it should be allowed it or not. I was thinking to use the e.user.getEmail() function and compare to my email/logon to prevent anyone else from making such changes. Is that a good design choice or can you suggest better?

```
Sample code --->

// Purpose: to notice whenever anyone tries to add, delete or hide rows and columns
// In most cases I want to prevent others from doing it, but let me do it

function myFunction(e) {          // catch any onChange events, e is the event object
  if (typeof e != "object") Logger.log('Ooopps - no error object passed to the function');
  let r = e.range;
  if(typeof r != "undefined") {   // as long as we have range data to test
    if (AND(OR(e.changeType == INSERT_ROW, e.changeType == REMOVE_ROW), r.row <  12)) {
      testAuth(e);                // only I can do these things to the top 11 rows
    } else if (OR(e.changeType == INSERT_COLUMN, e.changeType == REMOVE_COLUMN)) { 
      testAuth(e);                // only I can do these things to any of the columns
    } else if (e.changeType == OTHER) {
      // figure out how to determine what OTHER change was made and if it is OK
    } else {
      // any other changes such as EDIT, FORMAT or GRIDs are OK, nothing to do
    }
  }
}

function testAuth(e) {
  if (e.user.getEmail().toUpperCase() == 'MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS') {
    Logger.log('I changed something - OK');
  } else {
    // user did one of the bad things and it wasn't me doing it so prevent it
    Logger.log('Something changed but not by me - prevent it!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just ``protect`` the range?

Comment: The event object is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

Comment: This is the complete object `{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"INSERT_ROW","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}`... no  range available.  But you could have figured this out for yourself with `function onMyChange(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}`

Comment: @TheMaster - I want to allow data entry within the range just not adding/deleting columns, that's why I'm trying onChange instead of onEdit.

Comment: @TheMaster - I have seen that doc of the event object but it just seemed a little too thin on detail and I was hoping there was better. 1 - Looking for info on the changeType enum, including what OTHER means and how to differentiate between multiple OTHER type events. 2 - Looking for a way to get the range object that the user fiddled with.

Comment: @Cooper - thanks, good technique I hadn't consider (stringifying the object). So, no range data. Will have to figure out some other way to get at that, maybe with the ActiveRange. Any idea if the source or triggerUid parameters can provide me a way to determine more about just what happened that gets me to this onChange trigger? Kind of hoping that some of what I want is in the changeType == OTHER and these source and UID will help me further decode that.

Comment: The source is the current active spreadsheet.

Comment: `OTHER` is usually activated when there's a change made using [tag:google-sheets-api]. It's not really relevant in your case. In some cases, you can get the modified  range from `ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()` inside `onChange()`